# Freemarker doesn't see standart tag libraries in Struts2 project

Tags: jsp, jstl, freemarker

I am currently upgrading our web application from Webwork to Struts2. I run to problem with freemarker that I am unable to resolve.

In FTL file I have:

```
<#assign c=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"]>
```

When rendering the page I get:

```
JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"] is undefined.
```

I use other taglibs (e.g. spring and struts), I have them defined in `web.xml` and it works fine.

How can I make standard libraries work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the simplest thing. `/WEB-INF/lib` directory was not fully populated and it caused this error. I did full rebuild of the project and it works like magic now.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to tell you when talking about webapp's runtime classpath. The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is one of the paths covered by the default webapp's runtime classpath ... If you didn't understood what I meant with "webapp's runtime classpath", then you should have said that so. I would just have explained that in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This URI is deprecated over a decade ago. Use `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`. On the other hand, you also need to ensure that you've JSTL installed properly (by just placing/having  the JAR file(s) in the webapp's runtime classpath).